# How to open file in aptana from git terminal of aptana on windows?

Tags: terminal, aptana

I want to open file in aptana from aptana git terminal.
Is there a command line ?
I've tried something like

```
$ edit myfile.php
```

or

```
$ aptana myfile.php
```

but it doesn't works.

Thanks,

Comment: Nothing to do with git, removed tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can create shortcut by adding `alias aptana="/opt/aptana-studio-3/studio3  %F"` to your `.bashrc` file in your home folder. In my case aptana is installed in `opt/`. Find where it's installed in your computer and do as I mentioned. Now you can run aptana from terminal just by typing `aptana text.txt`

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal type:

start myfile.php

Answer (score 0):

Or from a mac:

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
add the following line:
alias aptana='open -a "AptanaStudio3"'
```

now simply open your files in aptana from terminal like this:

```
aptana index.html
```